# Windows Phone XAML and XNA app with ads

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to display ads from pubcetner in XNA game for WP. I am using DrawableAd class as it is written here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-xna-silverlight-hybrid-walkthrough-ads%28v=msads.20%29.aspx
But I can't see any ads rendering. Is it works? Or is there any other way to display ads? I wanted to try Adrotator, but I can't
get NuGet Package for this

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had a lot of problems with this in my game.

Without seeing your code, it's hard to actually diagnose, so without posting that from your Game.cs (assuming it's in Game.cs), you will need to make sure to test the following things.

```
//Global variable area
DrawableAd bannerAd;
string applicationID = "test_client"; //Or insert your actual ID. I recommend you first do with test client
                                      //ie. 1234567-d123-1234-a12b-1a23b4567890
string adUnitID = "Image480_80";      //Or the actual unit ID. ie. 123456


//Initialization
protected override void Initialize(){
    AdGameComponent.Initialize(this, applicationId);
    AdGameComponent.Current.CountryOrRegion = System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.TwoLetterISORegionName;
    bannerAd = AdGameComponent.Current.CreateAd(adUnitId, new Rectangle(0,400, 480, 80), true);
    AdGameComponent.Current.Enabled = true;
    AdGameComponent.Current.Visible = true;

    base.Initialize();
}
```

The part that got me by surprise was that I got rid of my base.Update(...) and base.Draw(...) calls and it actually prevented anything from ever being updated or called with the Ad.  I also remember through my endeavor that the region was apparently important in some cases. Can't find the source for that. You might be able to get rid of it.

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    //Your code here...

    base.Update(gameTime);
}

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    //Your code here...
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Hope that helps! Good luck. I know I had a pretty nasty time figuring out why mine didn't work.  Make sure your render order is correct to. I'm not sure, but perhaps you might be drawing everything ON the ad. I haven't looked into whether you could actually do that or if the depth field of the ad was always on top. I just leave my base.Draw(gameTime) at the bottom of everything else.

Comment: But I am using XAML and XNA app. It doesn't work there